# custom font prints random characters

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have the following code to print something:

```
class Print
{
    public static void print(string titel, string text, short i, Color color) {
        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
        doc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
        doc.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
        {
            e1.Graphics.DrawString(titel, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20), new SolidBrush(color), new PointF(30, 40));
            PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
            Stream fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".Barc.ttf");
            byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
            fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
            fontStream.Close();
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte * pFontData = fontdata)
                {
                    pfc.AddMemoryFont((System.IntPtr)pFontData, fontdata.Length);
                }
            }
            e1.Graphics.DrawString("*" + text + "*", new Font(pfc.Families[0], 20), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(30, 120));
        };
        doc.PrinterSettings.Copies = i;
        try
        {
            fd.BeginInvoke(doc, null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error while printing: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    private delegate void FunctionDelegate(PrintDocument doc);
    private static FunctionDelegate fd = new FunctionDelegate(doprint);

    private static void doprint(PrintDocument doc)
    {
        doc.Print();
    }
}
```

When I print something from my computer using (for example) `Print.print("A1439213616", "A1439213616", 1, Color.Black)` it will work correctly, using the barcode font to print the second line.
But when i copied my program onto another pc, it still printed the first line correctly, but the second line printed, in the default font instead of the custom font, `#3) ,  +1*) +. ) . #`. (the only pattern I've been able to spot so far is that the `*` are getting replaced with `#` everytime) Whats going wrong here? I am using .NET framework 3.5.

update: without changing anything, now 50% of the time it suddenly does print it correctly and 50% of the time its still the same as before.

Comment: I have made it so it will build up the font on init and save it in a variable, this just results in either all the prints will be correct or none at all.

Comment: I ended up simply making a server to print it for me because it worked just fine on all other computers.